# HTML tags not showing where they should be

Tags: html, html-email, web-inspector

I'm writing an html email and for some reason when I display it onto the browser, the inspector tool shows that the HTML is written differently than I how I wrote it.
How I wrote the html:

```
   <td align="center">
                    <table class="container" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table class="download" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                    </table>
                                   <table class="anatomy">
                                   </table>
                                   <table class="bytes" style="direction:1tr;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                   </table>
                                   <table class="netflix" style="margin-bottom: 50px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                   </table>
                                   <table class="month" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>
                   </table>                                 
   </td>
```

And the second one is how it looks on browser tools

```
<td align="center">
                    <table class="container" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table class="download" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                    </table>
                                   <table class="anatomy">
                                   </table>
                                   <table style="direction:ltr;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">               
                                   </table>
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>
                   </table>
                   <table class="bytes" style="direction:1tr;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                   </table>
                   <table class="netflix" style="margin-bottom: 50px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                   </table>
                   <table class="month" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                   </table>
</td>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: HTML in emails is a nightmare... Outlook/Exchange still uses ancient CSS rules! So you can work on getting emails presenting fine in Outlook, but then it's not showing as expected in Gmail.... you're not specifying where or with what tech you are writing this, but anyways beware of the changes in the rendering! :)

Comment: Your HTML is semantically incorrect! Why are you putting `<table>` inside `<td>`?

Comment: @Shahriar I figured that it would be the most effective to write out sections of the email. What do you recommend I do instead? Use ```<tr>```?

Comment: I think it's expecting at least one `<tr>` and `<td>` in each of the tables.